# Qt "The program has unexpectedly finished." on close

Tags: c++, qt

I have project on QML 2 (Qt 5.2.1). It seems works fine.

But when I close running project (<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>, or whatever) in Qt Creator's "Application Output" (that thing at the bottom), after 1-2 sec, I get the following message:

```
The program has unexpectedly finished.
bla-bla-bla.exe crashed
```

This happens in release and debug modes. I Launched under debug, but not got any errors. I follow step-by-step from my last destructor till the very `return app.exec();`, which return 1.

I mean except this - I don't see any errors. Should I worry about this? Can I know a reason for this message? Is there a way to get more specific message?

---

I tried to launch application from `cmd`, but not get any errors. My `main.cpp`:

```
#include <QtGui/QGuiApplication>
#include "qtquick2applicationviewer.h"
#include "painter.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    qmlRegisterType<Painter>("MyCanvas", 1, 0, "MyCanvas");

    QtQuick2ApplicationViewer viewer;
    viewer.setMainQmlFile(QStringLiteral("qml/test_painteditem/main.qml"));
    viewer.showExpanded();    

    return app.exec();
}
```

Main.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import MyCanvas 1.0

Rectangle {
    width: 360
    height: 360
    color: "white";
     focus: true;
    Keys.onLeftPressed: {
            mc.frame--;
            mc.update();
    }
    Keys.onRightPressed: {
            mc.frame++;
            mc.update();
    }
    Keys.onPressed: {
        if (event.key === Qt.Key_C){
             mc.switchCurve();
        }else if (event.key === Qt.Key_O){
            mc.switchCurveOffset();
       }    
   }

   MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            // mc.x += 10;
            //mc.update();
            if (!tim.running){
                tim.start();
            } else {
                tim.stop();
            }
        }
        onWheel: {
                if (wheel.angleDelta.y > 0)
                    mc.zoomIn();
                else
                    mc.zoomOut();
        }
        onPressed: {    
        }
    }

    Timer {
        id:tim
        interval: 1; running: false; repeat: true
        onTriggered:  {    
            mc.frame++;
            mc.update();
        }
    }    

    MyCanvas {
        id:mc;
        x:0;
        y:0;
        width:1000;         /** 2000x2000 not supported in Android  */
        height:1000;
    }
}
```

Comment: And what do you want we do without any code and any specific error message?

Comment: I would worry if  I see that in my program :)

Comment: I can't put there code of my project, but maybe there is a way to get more specific error message? Because that message that I showed is the only one I see.

Comment: Debug your program until you find the error. When `exec` is called the Qt part of your program start. Set some breakpoint and try to localize the point in which crashes.

Comment: But I said that I not got errors even with step-by-step debug. It does not crashes literally. It just show that message after I close application. Even in step by step to the end - it show that error when debugger stops.

Comment: please add some code!

Comment: Well I can't add all code. I have qml, which have C++ component. And that component really big, and it includes another library which is even bigger. Maybe I can find something in Windows Log?

Comment: Make a copy of your project, compile it, see if you still get the error. If so, try commenting out as much of your code as possible so that you get a very small program which still produces that error. Once you have that, share the whole source code of that problematic program so we can figure out a solution much more easily.

Comment: Maybe is something related to the fact that when you hit ALT+F4 the QML Timer `tim` is still running? Does the problem happens even if the timer is stopped when you hit ALT+F4? I mean: if you launch the program and do not start the timer (that is you don't click on your MouseArea) the problem is there anyway?

Comment: @MorixDev You know, now I noticed that it crushes always in release mode, and each second in debug. I think there is something in my `MyCanvas`, because when I remove it from QML it not show errors more.

Answer (score 2):

There is a [`app.quit()`](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#quit) method you could call or connect to, when exiting your Qt application. Apart from that a return value of 1 might not what Qt creator is expecting. You want a return value equal to `EXIT_SUCCESS` (or `0`).

Comment: It works without any error messages now. But is this valid way? And one more - I read about `aboutToQuit`. Should I worry about it?

Comment: Calling or connecting to `quit()` is a valid way. Manually returning `EXIT_SUCCESS` is cheating, of course, but it solves the problem. I would recommend simplifying / reducing the amount of executed code to see if this problem always exists or if you can located a bug this way.